# Opening a second window from an IBAction

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ibaction, touch-event

How do I use a second window I created, is there a way to open it when triggering an `IBAction` event, e.g., a "touch down" event?

Comment: What kind of windows? NSWindows? UIWindows? X windows? MS Windows? WxWidget Windows? What platform are you on? What framework do you use? What OS?

Comment: Tagged with XCode... Don't think XCode run on another OS than OSX...

Comment: @Macmade Xcode is an IDE which can be used in conjunction with **any** compiler you want. If you want to compile for Microsoft Windows and you have a compiler that runs on Mac OS X but compiles for Windows, Xcode can be used with that compiler.

Comment: Mmmmhhhh... Compiling Obj-C MSWindows apps with XCode... Why not... ; )

Comment: @Macmade you are an Objective-C programmer who applies the Obj-C coding conventions even to Microsoft products: `MSWindows`. Funny. :') `[MSWindows showBlueScreenOfDeathWithPointer:ptr];`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, you create the window in a separate XIB file, and create a subclass of NSWindowController, that you set as the file owner of the XIB file.

Then, you need to override the init method to load the XIB file:

```
- ( id )init
{
    if( ( self = [ super initWithWindowNibName: @"MySecondWindow" ] ) )
    {}

    return self;

}
```

Then, you just need to create a new instance of your second window controller, and show the window:

```
MyWindowController * wc = [ MyWindowController new ];
[ wc showWindow: nil ];
```

That can be done from your IBAction method.

Comment: Thank You Very Much This Works Great No where gave this apart from IOS development docs but they are confusing sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand a tiny bit on what Macmade stated:

I prefer the formal allocating memory and initializing the object.

```
MyWindowController * wc = [[MyWindowController alloc] init];
[wc.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
```

Comment: I see... So i replace the variable > wc <. Thank you so much for helping me out Arvin.